# wfresh not working with WS-Federation via ADFS

Tags: asp.net, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, adfs, ws-federation

I have an application that authenticates against ADFS 2 via WS-Federation.  I look for a specific claim when I get the response back from ADFS and based on that claim, I am able to authorize the user into my application.  I want to create an enhancement in which when a user authenticates against ADFS and comes back to my application WITHOUT the claim I require, that I redirect them back to the Identity Provider (ADFS), but this time FORCING them to provide their credentials again.  I wrote my code to detect an authenticated user that is missing the claim I require and sends them back to reauthenticate, this time sending along the "Freshness" parameter (wfresh=0).  I was under the impression that this would prompt the user for credentials but it seems to just reuse the original credentials which, of course, causes an infinate loop (that ADFS halts.)  How can I achieve this?

My URL looks like this when I send them back to the IdP after not having the required claim:

```
https://somedomain.com/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fanotherdomain.com%2flogin.ashx&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fanotherdomain%2flogin.ashx&wctx=1106273&wfresh=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wfresh on integrated does not make sense. You are always signed into AD and cannot signout. The story is probably different for forms based authentication. But haven't tried that in ADFS.

Comment: So there is no way, that you know of, to force a prompt for credentials?  It's funny because if I am logged into my machine using a domain account and I hit the site, I am not asked for credentials and I am just signed right in, but if I'm logged in as a local user (I am always prompted the first time, then it caches it until I close the browser)

Comment: You can probably use wauth to show the login form. But from an AD point of view, domain users are always signed in. That's the whole point.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up passing "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password" as the AuthenticationType for my SignInRequestMessage and was presented the login form.  Is this what you were suggesting?  It seems to work but I'm not 100% sure if that is the correct URI to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the default for wfresh is zero.

Have you tried it without wfresh?

Also, you could logout - [AD FS: How to Invoke a WS-Federation Sign-Out](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx).

Comment: Having similar problems, and attempting to force the service to disregard or not add the wfresh parameter - do you have a method for doing so? I can't find anything that works.