# wfresh parameter causing ADFS login to fail

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs, ws-federation

I am using ADFS to do federated logins with a number of different RPs, including our own custom web app, Office 365 and some other third-party services. I have run into a problem where logins silently fail when the `wfresh=0` is specified in the URL. It just keeps asking for my password over and over again. When I click the "Login" button, it doesn't log you in and redirect you to back to the RP, nor does it fail and give you an error message. Instead, it redirects you back to the STS login page, so it looks to the user like it's silently failing.

I found this question: [wfresh not working with WS-Federation via ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223809/wfresh-not-working-with-ws-federation-via-adfs), which seems to be on the right track. However, while I am definitely seeing issues with integrated logins, I am getting similar issues with Forms logins as well. The outward symptoms are different, but the behavior seems to be the same: If you specify `wfresh=0`, it sends you directly to /adfs/ls.

Is there any way to configure ADFS to treat `wfresh` correctly, or at least to ignore it?

Update: Cross-posted to MSDN Geneva Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7acbbd11-cd69-466b-8faa-f129f24fe1fe/wfresh-parameter-causing-adfs-login-to-fail

Comment: I've finally got some word from Microsoft on this: They know about it. That's basically all I've got for now. I'll update if/when I get more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Microsoft today released their hotfix for this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896713. It is not a public hotfix, so you will need to contact Microsoft support to get the update.

Previous: I spoke with an Escalation Engineer in Global Escalation Services for Microsoft. The EE said they are aware of this issue, tracking impacted customers, and working on a solution.  Anyone who is experiencing this same problem should contact Microsoft support and open a support case so they are notified when the solution is available.  Microsoft support is tracking this issue internally under solution id number 2879919.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing as of lately. We have connections with some RPs and also use Office 365. If I leave my machine logged into portal.microsoftonline.com it will eventually show "page cannot be displayed" with the URL showing the long string and "wfresh=0" at the end.

Externally, if i leave my browser logged into the portal it will take me back to the form but never accept my new credentials. If I change the value of "wfresh=0" to "1" it allows me back in external and internal. I'm trying to review event logs to see anything but have not found any clues. still looking.

Comment: I've noticed the same things. I am telling my users to delete the wfresh parameter from the URL as a temporary workaround, but that's not a long-term solution. I wish I knew if this started because Microsoft's STS started sending wfresh, or because ADFS stopped accepting it. I'll have to check my logs tomorrow morning.

Comment: Checked my logs. It appears that this started between 8/5 and 8/15. 8/5 is the last time I see a request containing wfresh that worked, and 8/15 was the first time I saw one that didn't work. I'm not sure why there was no wfresh requests for that time in between, but it could just be that I didn't have any users leaving pages open during that time (We have a small enough number of employees that this might actually be possible).

Comment: We installed KB2843638 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843638) and KB2843639 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843639) on 8/14. These may be the issue. Haven't looked yet.

Comment: I have the same one installed too on my AD FS farm servers. It says there are additional steps required to complete the installation. I'm going to run them in my lab instance and see what happens!

Comment: I ran through the recommended steps and didn't see a difference. I also uninstalled the patch which broke it altogether. Do you use custom claim rules at all?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "custom". I did add rules to the Issuance Transform Rules tab for the affected RP, but it just used the standard rule wizard. I didn't write custom language myself or anything like that.

Comment: I use a custom claim rule for Office 365. In my lab I reinstalled the KB2843638 patch that I had uninstalled earlier. That at least let me back in. 

I've also gone ahead and updated to Security Rollup 3 in lab and am leaving the browser session open at: Portal.microsoftonline.com. I'll update if it anything positive happens. 

And I've also gone thru my IIS logs and have noted wfresh exists as far back as June in my logs. I don't see any errors there at least. I'm using CMTRACE to view them.

Comment: I noticed the same. wfresh has been present in the logs for a long time. But the weird behavior started on 8/15. You can recognize it in the logs pretty easily. For internal it's obvious because you get 8 or more log entries within the same second, all with wfresh=0, all with 302 responses, alternating between /adfs/ls and /adfs/ls/internal. For external it's not quite so obvious, but you'll see a group within a few seconds where there's a 200 (when the user first visits) followed by pairs of a 302 and a 200 (each time they enter their credentials and it fails).

Comment: Thanks for the details! I've got a case open with O365 support on tier 3.

Comment: So far not getting much traction on the issue with the escalation team for O365. I got routed to the IE team where they let me know it was an AD FS issues. The AD FS team let me know this was expected behavior :\
Obviously something changed with a security update. I've let my lab update with MSFT update. I will see if it took any new patches in regards to AD FS.

Comment: Ha. I got the same from the AD FS team for a long time. Eventually we found someone who knew what was going on. See my answer above. Tell them to look up "solution id number 2879919". This is an internal tracking number for Microsoft, but the guy at MS I talked to said this should point your support engineer in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome! Did you put this on the AD FS server and proxies?

Comment: Yes. We've had it in place for a month now and have not had any more problems. The only thing is that it's not a public hotfix, you have to call up MS Support and ask for it.

Comment: oh, I see! I saw that in your notes. So the KB you linked is what I ended up installing in my lab and I've left the portal open for about 4 hours and it has not gone to the "page cannot be displayed" is the KB you called in for different then?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be a good or bad solution (if possible) to use MS IIS URL rewrite to replace or remove wfresh=0 from the URL when hitting the IIS?

Best would of course be if the default installation of ADFS worked with wfresh=0 in the first place :-)

IIS URL Rewrite[1](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

---

### ***Update:***

My problem was that only internal clients experienced the error while external clients (using the ADFS proxy servers) did not.

With URL rewrite on the internal ADFS 2.1 servers and the following URL rewrite rule in /adfs/ls/web.config works:

```
    <rule name="wfresh0to1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)wfresh=0(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}?{C:1}wfresh=1{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into this on Monday, though I was hoping it would be a last resort after finding an actual fix.

Comment: I looked into this at one point... In my mind I have the thought that it won't work, but I don't remember how I came to that conclusion. I agree with Jeeva, though, a real fix would be better.

Comment: A little further investigation... I figured out a regular expression that should work. Match the pattern: `/adfs/ls/\?(.*)(&wfresh=0)(.*)`, replace it with `/adfs/ls/?{R:1}{R:3}`. But I tried this and it didn't seem to be working. It's possible that the logic that governs AD FS happens before IIS hits the rewrite module, or that I'm doing something else wrong in the way I'm configuring it.

Comment: The method in the update works fine for me. Still waiting on a real fix from Microsoft, though.